# Setting a groups cover image using the Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, curl

I've been visiting this forum for years, but this is my first ever question. Any help would be appreciated!

I am writing a web service to pass groups from one application into Facebook and invite the authorised people into them and set a nice pretty cover photo that is generated and stored within the application.

The group creation works splendidly after a fair old bit of head scratching, however, when I try to set the cover image, I am getting a rather useful error message back as below.

```
OAuth "Facebook Platform" "unknown_error" "An unknown error has occurred."
```

It's a PHP application on Code Igniter. According to [Facebook's delightfully accurate API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/app-game-groups/#set_cover_photo), this is a simple matter of a cUrl post to 'graph.facebook.com/$groupId' passing the same auth token I just used to create the group and perform the invites and a single JSON encoded parameter of 'cover_url' => $urlOfImage .

A simple task in theory, however, I have spent all day today and a significant chunk of yesterday trying to get this to work without much success.

I have tried posting the image as a Curl object as is necessary in other areas of the Facebook API, and it appears to be trying giving me an error that the image is generating a 404 error (it isn't, when I checked the access logs, it was never requested).

Please be someone out there who has had some success with this.

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested. I have reported this as a bug to Facebook. I'll update as and when they fix it.

Comment: This has now been fixed by Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been fixed by Facebook